# Passing values from JavaServlet to Javascript, calling a Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

So there is an old code base I am leveraging from work, currently they are sending over 2 items from an object and I'm adding a third. The third object I'm sending in JAVA as a string, however in the communication over to javascript it's freaking out, I'm getting a horrible error as prototype is declaring it undefined, however I'm watching the code being sent.

Currently the Java code is calling the function. Passing the following data over. All of these are strings.

setCCInfo(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx2205, 1219, 60W76W);

When I remove the final variable, and pass just the first two the function works, however it's almost like prototype is expecting a numeral as I had to change the other two into strings when it got to the front end. I'll attach the code below. The current Error I'm getting is

> "prototype-1.6.0.2.js:394 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected
>   token
>       at prototype-1.6.0.2.js:394
>       at prototype-1.6.0.2.js:635
>       at prototype-1.6.0.2.js:595
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Array.each (prototype-1.6.0.2.js:594)
>       at Array.collect (prototype-1.6.0.2.js:634)
>       at String.evalScripts (prototype-1.6.0.2.js:394)
>       at Function. (prototype-1.6.0.2.js:209)
>       at prototype-1.6.0.2.js:231"

```
ctx.getResponse().getWriter().print(output.getString("TCResultStatus").toUpperCase());
                                    StringBuilder str = buildJavascriptCall(cceft);
                                    ctx.getResponse().getWriter().print(str.toString());

private StringBuilder buildJavascriptCall(CcEft cceft) {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                str.append("<script type='text/javascript'>setCCInfo(");
                str.append(cceft.getMaskedCCNum());
                str.append(", ");
                str.append(cceft.getCombinedExpDate());
                str.append(", ");
                str.append(cceft.getBillingId());
                str.append(");</script>");
                return str;
            }
```

Comment: Prolly put quotes around strings.

Comment: yeah might have too, or pull a tostring method on the final one.

Comment: Your example setCCInfo should be `setCCInfo("xxxxxxxx2205", "1219", "60W76W")` with quotes (single or double) around each string (possible that the middle one isn't a string)